# Mockito Repetition in Stubbing and Verification

Tags: java, junit, mockito

It seems that in certain cases, EasyMock stubbing can take the place of verification. Take the following trivial example:

Class A:

```
public class A {
    private B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    int main(int input) {
        return b.timesThree(input + 4);
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class B {
    int timesThree(int input) {
        return input * 3;
    }
}
```

Class ATest:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ATest {
    @Mock
    B b;

    @InjectMocks
    A a;

    @Test
    void testMain() {
        doReturn(21).when(b).timesThree(7);

        int result = a.main(3);
        assertEquals(21, result);

        verify(b).timesThree(7);
    }

}
```

Is there a point to the `verify` call? The `when` call already asserts the input parameter to `b.timesThree()` is 7.

Comment: In your example, you don't need to call `doReturn()` and should call `verify()` since you're dealing with primitives specifically.

Comment: Well, if you absolutely want to make sure that the call to timesThree has been made, then it's useful. Otherwise, it's not. Without the verify, the test would pass if the code was replaced by `return 21;`. This is a highly unlikely situation, so I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @PankajGadge wouldn't that cause the B mock to return 0 when its `timesThree` method is called? In any event, the primitives were just to keep the question simple, but my main intent was to understand what the value of using `verify` is in these particular types of cases.

Comment: If you are also unit testing that `B.timesThree()` works as expected (which you should be) then I would think it's unneeded to verify it's being called in addition to the stub if it's working as expected. Seems overkill in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In this case no. It comes down to what you are really trying to assert in the test.

Here you are trying to test that when main method is called with a value 2 things should happen

1. timesThree should be called with value+4
2. value returned from timesThree should be returned by your main function

Since in your test the below three lines is enough to assert both the above cases you don't need a verify here.

```
doReturn(21).when(b).timesThree(7);
int result = a.main(3);
assertEquals(21, result);
```

The easiest way to find out if your test is good enough is by commenting out parts of your implementation and making your test fail (TDD). As long as you get a failing test you are good.

Ex: change 4 to 5 - test fails, remove input test fails

Suppose your timesThree method did not return a value, but instead stored it somewhere

```
int main(int input) {
//Stores value somwhere
    b.timesThree(input + 4);
}
```

Here you test has to assert that timesThree is called once with the value 7.
In this case you need a verify, since you will never be able to get a failing test without verify.

Also on a side note one of the comments mentioned "the test would pass if the code was replaced by return 21;"

To proof your test against this consider using a random integer instead of hardcoding values. This will make sure there is no accidental hard coding in your implementation. 
Example library for random intgers
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/RandomUtils.html#nextInt()